# How to create a new website with existing website setting in Magento

Tags: magento, web, settings

Is there a way in Magento when creating a new website to copy all setting from a existing website?

Can I copy setting from database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need config data - just copy "core_config_data" table from your database.